# useState not updating Grandparent state - data passes from Grandchild to child succesfully, but no further

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have an 'Autocomplete' grandchild React component which takes data from the child component, helps the user autocomplete a form field, and then passes the value right back up to the grandparent component which posts the whole form.

I am able to get data from grandchild to child, but not able to get the data from there up to the grandparent.

**Grandparent - AddPost.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GetBeerStyle from './GetBeerStyle';

export default function AddPost(props) {

const [parentBeerStyleData, setParentBeerStyleData] = useState("")

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

// There's some code here that pulls the  data together and posts to the backend API

    }

    return (
    <div>
            <GetBeerStyle
                    name="beerstyle"
                        beerStyleData={childData => setParentBeerStyleData(childData)}
                        onChange={console.log('Parent has changed')}
        />

        // More data input fields are here...

    </div>
    );
}
```

**Child - GetBeerStyle.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Autocomplete from '../Autocomplete';

export default function GetBeerStyle(props) {

    const [beerStyleData, setBeerStyleData] = useState("")
    const [beerStyles, setBeerStyles] = useState(null)
    const apiURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/styles/"
     
    // Code to fetch the beer styles from the API and push down to the grandchild
    // component to enable autocomplete

    const fetchData = async  () => {
        const response = await axios.get(apiURL)
        const fetchedStyles = Object.values(response.data)
        const listOfStyles = []

        for (let i = 0; i < fetchedStyles.length; i++) {
            (listOfStyles[i] = fetchedStyles[i].style_name)
        }
    setBeerStyles(listOfStyles)
    }; 

    // This snippet pulls data from the Posts table via the API when this function is called
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="one-cols">
            <Autocomplete 
                suggestions={ beerStyles }                             // sending the data down to gchild
                parentUpdate={childData => setBeerStyleData(childData)}// passing data back to gparent
                onChange={() => props.beerStyleData(beerStyleData)}               
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Grandchild - Autocomplete.jsx**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment, useState } from 'react';

export default function Autocomplete(props) {

    const [activeSuggestion, setActiveSuggestion] = useState(0);
    const [filteredSuggestions, setFilteredSuggestions] = useState([]);
    const [showSuggestions, setShowSuggestions] = useState(false);
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
    const [fieldId, setFieldId] = useState("");
    const [parentUpdate, setParentUpdate] = useState("");

    const onChange = e => {

        const { suggestions } = props;

        setActiveSuggestion(0);
        setFilteredSuggestions(suggestions.filter(suggestion => suggestion.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) >-1));
        setShowSuggestions(true);
        setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value);
        setParentUpdate(e.currentTarget.value);
        (console.log(parentUpdate));

        return props.parentUpdate(parentUpdate);
    };

    const onClick = e => {

        setActiveSuggestion(0);
        setFilteredSuggestions([]);
        setShowSuggestions(false);
        setUserInput(e.currentTarget.innerText);
        setFieldId(props.fieldId);
        setParentUpdate(e.currentTarget.innerText);

        return props.parentUpdate(parentUpdate);
    };

    const onKeyDown = e => {

        // User pressed the ENTER key
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            setActiveSuggestion(0);
            setShowSuggestions(false);
            setUserInput(filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]);

        // User pressed the UP arrow    
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
                return;
            }
            setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion - 1);
        }

        // User pressed the DOWN arrow
          else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
              if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
                  return;
              }
              setActiveSuggestion(activeSuggestion + 1);
          }  
    };

        let suggestionsListComponent;

        if (showSuggestions && userInput) {
            if (filteredSuggestions.length) {
                suggestionsListComponent = (
                    <ul class="suggestions">
                        {filteredSuggestions.map((suggestion, index) => {
                            let className;

                            // Flag the active suggestion with a class
                            if (index === activeSuggestion) {
                                className = "suggestion-active";
                            }
                            return (
                                <li className={className} key={suggestion} onClick={onClick}>
                                    {suggestion}
                                    
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                );
            } else {
                suggestionsListComponent = (
                    <div class="no-suggestions">
                        <em>No Suggestions Available.</em>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={userInput}
                onChange={onChange}
                onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
                id={fieldId}
            />
            <div>
                {suggestionsListComponent}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
        );
}
```

While I certainly accept there may be other issues with the code, overriding problem that I seem to have spent an inordinate amount of time googling and researching, is that I can't get the data being entered in the form input, to pull through to the grandparent component!

What have I missed?

Comment: Try `props.onChange(e.currentTarget.value)` at the start of `onChange` in the grandchild

Comment: Thanks Nadia, that's done the trick! At a high level, what does this change in the logic?

Comment: It seems you've very much inconsistently named props you are passing down. To start with, you don't even pass an `onChange` callback from "parent" `AddPost` to its child. Then in the "child" component `GetBeerStyle` you appear to switch your data prop to the `onChange` prop being passed to the "grandchild" `AutoComplete`. `Autocomplete` then doesn't seem to use the passed `onChange` prop at all.

Comment: As Drew Reese says, you were not calling the right callback. Try to give all of your functions unique names so if you accidentally call the wrong one, the compiler is more likely to pick it up. And don't call anything onChange to distinguish you methods from the javascript onchange event, that should make things a bit less confusing

Comment: Thanks both! Will go forth and refactor now that I've got the data flowing! Only problem now is the data being passed to the grandparent is two steps behind lol ;)

Comment: Each child level seems to have a lot of state, and I suspect you are essentially duplicating state in the children. In other words you update the state in a child and then pass *what you think is the updated state* to the callback. If you do this between a Parent-Child then what is passed to the parent appears to be a "render cycle" delayed. If you do this repetitively then each time delays the update another render cycle. You should strive for a single source of truth. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) for explanation and example of pattern.